# Program That Only Uses Virtual Memory On Linux

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

I have a question about Linux and it's virtual memory.

- How can I write a program that would only take up virtual memory on Linux

To elaborate a bit further. When using the top command on Linux on ise presented with all the processes and the memory they are taking. From virtual to resident and event shared memory. But what I want is to write a program that would only use virtual memory and both res and shr would be at 0.

- This question occured to me while using the stress command, because the top command showed that it used a lot of virtual memory and only a little bit of residential memory.

Thank you for your time and I look forward to reading your answers!

Comment: if a thing is virtual it exists in effect, but not in reality.  Have a think about that

Answer (score 0):

Program cannot be run unless it is loaded into the actual memory of the computer.

Virtual memory is only a temporary store on hard disk, which is meant for keeping copies of snapshots called '**pages**' from the actual memory.

The page will be executed by CPU only if it is in the actual memory.

A page kept in virtual memory will not be executed by CPU.

Comment: So it would be impossible to run with only virtual memory?

Comment: Yes. Physical memory is needed for the execution. Virtual memory is just a special space reserved on the hard disk for temporary storage of pages from the actual memory. It is not feasible to run a program directly from virtual memory.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much! Can I just ask one more thing? How would I avoid using the shared memory? Because  even if I do not use the libraries it still gets used. Thank you very much for your time and looking forward to your answer!

Comment: 'Shared memory' applies to the physical memory only. It is a useful feature of the operating system and cannot be disabled completely. Shared memory may be disabled for specific cases (Example: Graphics card) through BIOS settings. Shared memory segments can be deleted if a program had crashed. (Example: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/tuning_and_optimizing_red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_oracle_9i_and_10g_databases/sect-oracle_9i_and_10g_tuning_guide-setting_shared_memory-removing_shared_memory)